# Find lim$_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right).$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right) = \frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x\sin x}=  \frac{0}{0}.$$

L'Hopital's: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{\sin ^2x} = \frac{0}{0}.$$

Once again, using L'Hopital's: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f''(x)}{g''(x)} = \frac{2}{x^3}- \frac{2\cos x}{\sin ^3x} = \frac{0}{0}\,\ldots$$ The terms are getting endless here. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You are misusing L'Hospital's Rule. It applies to **quotients** and you must differentiate top and bottom.

Comment: That's how I was doing it. I just didn't write it down like that for the sake of time.

Comment: You were not. There is no way you can differentiate top and bottom of $\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x}$ and get what you got. We get $\frac{x\sin x}{x\cos x+\sin x}$.

Comment: **Please** do not write question titles composed entirely of a formula.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Maybe that's where I did my mistake.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was doing it like this: lim$_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - g'(x)f(x)}{[g(x)]^2}$ and kept squaring the denominator.

Comment: You are using the Quotient Rule  for differentiating $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. For L'Hospital you must differentiate $f$ and $g$ **separately.**

Comment: @Jellyfish You need to think carefully about what you mean by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  What does $f'(x)$ mean?  What does $g'(x)$ mean?  What is $f'(x)/g'(x)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-(\cos x-x\sin x)}{\sin x+x\cos x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\sin x}{\sin x+x\cos x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \cos x}\\&=\frac{0}{1+1\cdot 1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

Learn to love asymptotics;

$$\frac {\tan x - x}{x \tan x} \sim \frac{x + x^3/3 - x}{x^2} \sim x/3 \to 0$$

Comment: nice method ant ! :D

Answer (score 4):

Use Taylor-MacLaurin at order $2$:
\begin{align*}\frac1x - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}&=\frac1x - \frac{1-\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)}{x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o(x^3)}=\frac1x-\frac1x\left(\frac{1-\smash[t]{\dfrac{x^2}2}+o(x^2)}{1-\smash[b]{\dfrac{x^2}6}+o(x^2)}\right)\\&=\frac1x-\frac1x\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}3+o(x^2)\Bigr)= \frac x3+o(x)\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0.\end{align*}

Comment: You're right, I was to fast! Thank you for pointing it. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(x)+x\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\cos(x)}=0$

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
-\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{\sin ^2x}
$$
You can't apply L'Hopital's rules to either of the two fractions above since the numerators do not approach $0$ or $\pm\infty$.  But you can first add the fractions and *then* use L'Hopital's rule:
$$
-\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{\sin ^2x} = \frac{-\sin^2 x + x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^5)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Comment: This misses the crucial step.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned it, I will go for the overkill. $\cot z$ is a meromorphic function on the complex plane and $\frac{1}{z}$ is exactly its singular part in the origin, since:
$$ \sin z = z \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
implies:
$$ \log \sin z = \log z + \sum_{n\geq 1}\log\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{2} $$
then:
$$ \cot z = \frac{1}{z}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{n^2\pi^2-z^2}\tag{3} $$
as well as:
$$ \frac{1}{z}-\cot z = 2z\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2-z^2}=2z\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{\pi^4}z^2+\frac{\zeta(6)}{\pi^6}z^6+\ldots\right)\tag{4}$$
so the wanted limit is just zero. By the way, the last formula allows us to compute the values of the zeta function over the positive even integers in terms of the derivatives of $z\cot z$ at $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. I'll definitely try that once I've mastered the "not so difficult" ones :)